# Detect which App was launched using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When an external app is launched using `UIActivityViewController`, can we detect which app was used in the `completionHandler`?

In [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/completionwithitemshandler), there is mention of a property `UIActivity.ActivityType`, but it seems this is used only to detect "built-in activities". How can I detect if, eg. WhatsApp Messenger was launched?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When setting up your `UIActivityViewController`, use the `completionWithItemsHandler` to setup a completion closure that is called when the user makes a selection.

This completion block takes four parameters: the (optional) selected activity, a completion indicator, an optional array of returned items, and an error.

The selected activity is of type `UIActivity.ActivityType`. Its `rawValue` is a `String` representing the activity. If the activity type isn't one of the provided constants, compare its `rawValue` against a string you determine by running some tests to see its value for a given activity such as WhatsApp.

Comment: So how would I know the expected app name? Is there a list of 3rd party activity names I can compare with?

Comment: As I said, you need to find the value by running your app and selecting WhatsApp, for example. See what value is returned. Then you can hardcode that string into your code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

### In Objective-C

You can use this code to know which activity was used

```
shareSheetVC.completionWithItemsHandler  = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *error){
              
       if (completed) {
                 
            NSLog(@"Shared by activity %@", activityType);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"ShareSheet was closed");
        }
       
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An Error occured: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);
                 
        }
 };
```

#### Output when I shared using WhatsApp

[image]